# How to find the bug in this swap function (a singly linked list)?

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I am unable to swap values in a linked list if one of them is a head. I am inserting three values(4, 5, 7) in a and deleting 2 and swapping 5, 4 but the code doesn't swap when one of the values is a head and it just doesn't swap and display a output when one of them is a head the same code works good for non-head nodes

```
struct node
{
int x;

node* next;
};

void swapper(node **headref, int a, int b)
{
    node *temp1 = *headref, *temp2 = *headref, *prev2 = NULL, *prev1 = NULL;

    while(temp1 != NULL && temp1->x != a)
    {
        prev1 = temp1;
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }

    while(temp2 != NULL && temp2->x != b)
    {
        prev2 = temp2;
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }

    if(temp1 == *headref)
    {
        swap(temp1->next, temp2->next);
        prev2->next = *headref;
        *headref = temp2;
    }

    if(temp2 == *headref)
    {
        swap(temp1->next, temp2->next);
        prev1->next = *headref;
        *headref = temp1;
    }

    if(temp1 != NULL && temp2 != NULL)
    {
        swap(prev1->next, prev2->next);
        swap(temp1->next, temp2->next);
    }
}
```

```
Output:

4 1 2 3
4 1 2 5 3 
4 1 2 5 3 7 
4 1 5 3 7
```

It is supposed to swap 5 and 4 and display 5 1 4 3 7 but this doesn't happen. I am not able to find the bug in the code.

Comment: The definition of `node` is still missing. Please read about how one provides a [mcve]. Reading [How to debug small program (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) can also help you.

Comment: Do you really need to swap the nodes themselves? Why not just swap the values inside the nodes instead?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention  the question is to swap the nodes them selves not the values (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/swap-nodes-in-a-linked-list-without-swapping-data/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't thought through the different cases properly. If you need to swap then you should only do a single swap, so you should have an if ... else if ... else statement to handle the different cases.

What's going wrong specifically in your example is that `temp1 == *headref` then a swap happens, but after the swap `temp2 == *headref` so the program attempts a second swap.

You also have a bug if you attempt to swap the head with something that's not in the list, in that case you would have (for instance) `temp1 == *headref` and `temp2 == NULL` which would be a problem.

A final bug is swapping a head with itself. That also crashes because `prev2 == NULL` in that case.

Here's a version that works. As you can see it's very similar to yours, I've just thought through the different ways to swap a little more carefully.

```
void swapper(node **headref, int a, int b)
{
    node *temp1 = *headref, *temp2 = *headref, *prev2 = NULL, *prev1 = NULL;

    while (temp1 != NULL && temp1->x != a)
    {
        prev1 = temp1;
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }

    while (temp2 != NULL && temp2->x != b)
    {
        prev2 = temp2;
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }

    if (temp1 == NULL || temp2 == NULL || temp1 == temp2)
    {
        // nothing to do
    }
    else if (temp1 == *headref)
    {
        swap(temp1->next, temp2->next);
        prev2->next = *headref;
        *headref = temp2;
    }
    else if (temp2 == *headref)
    {
        swap(temp1->next, temp2->next);
        prev1->next = *headref;
        *headref = temp1;
    }
    else
    {
        swap(prev1->next, prev2->next);
        swap(temp1->next, temp2->next);
    }
}
```

Having said all that I really am impressed with the quality of the code you wrote. The style is good, it's easy to follow, it was close to being correct and easily fixed once the bugs were found.

Comment: Thanks a lot!For helping even though my question was down voted :)